# Bootstrap Why are my columns wider than the container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out why my 4 columns put together are wider than the container they are in.
Can tell me how to fix my code so that the group of column fits perfectly inside their parent container?

Thanks.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>



body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.container{
 padding:0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border:solid 1px blue;
 width:100%;
 }
.col-md-3{
 border:solid 1px red;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

.col-md-3 .btn{
display:block;
border: 1px solid green;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you making your own css for bootstrap?

You may want to try to get a theme and edit it that way - but I think you can get what you are after by adding some padding to your rows.

Try this css:

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.container{
 padding:0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border:solid 1px blue;
 width:100%;
 }
.row {
padding:0.5%;
}
.col-md-3{
 border:solid 1px red;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

.col-md-3 .btn{
display:block;
border: 1px solid green;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to make the page full-width. Try this.

**Here is the default CSS.**

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

The above default is @min-width:1200px

```
.container-fluid {
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
.col-md-3 {
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-md-3 .btn {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can use `container-fluid`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"> <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"> <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"> <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"> <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed working. I have got another question though. How comes the columns are still wider than their parent container if I leave padding:0 inside container-fluid in my css? Is there a default padding? I'd like to understand why your solution works. Thanks.

Comment: I added the default CSS to my answer so you can see it.